# How to upload and display images in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to ask you how can I properly stored an image both in mysql and in a folder at the moment with this code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) { 

          // Temporary file name stored on the server
          $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  

          // Read the file 
          $fp     = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
          $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
          $data = addslashes($data);
          fclose($fp);


          // Create the query and insert
          // into our database.
          $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images ";
          $query .= "(images) VALUES ('$data')";
          $results = mysql_query($query, $conn);

          // Print results
          print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";

}
else {
   print "No image selected/uploaded";
}


if (!mysql_query($sql, $link))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }

?>'
```

Also how properly to display it.
My database for the images is id, images. Do I need anything more for the job or that is enough.
Thank you.

Comment: why not check `if($results)  print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";`

Comment: try.. just store the image path in database and image in server ... and just fetch the image path from database and show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above code, image will be saved in database not in folder.
To save in folder you have to use a below code after insert query.

```
move_uploaded_file($tmpName,"upload/" .$filename );
```

here upload is folder name.

Comment: I have tried this 

    move_uploaded_file($tmpName,"upload/" .$filename );

but it tells me the following errors:

    Notice: Undefined variable: filename
    Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory 
    Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'D:\wamp\tmp\php2EC4.tmp' to 'D:/wamp/www/2ro-2012-2013/upload/'

Comment: here $filename is $tmpName.

Comment: So i have to say move_uploaded_file($tmpName,"upload/" .$tmpName); or i got it wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store image in database you can use [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) method

```
$image = file_get_contents('filename.gif');
$imencoded = base64_encode($image);   
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images ";
$query .= "(images) VALUES ('$imencoded')";
```

But storing image in db is not recommended and it will not support in IE6 & 7.